# What is difference between knowledgeSession.fireAllRules() and knowledgeSession.fireAllRules(1) in Drools ?

Tags: drools

My use case is to return the first matched rule and not to match all other the rules. Is there a way to do this? what is the significance of knowledgeSession.fireAllRules(max) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the fireAllRules(max) method basically takes the amount of rule matches that you want. All it does internally is creating an AgendaFilter that limits the amount of matches. (See AgendaFilter interface docs). Skipping the argument means using a filter that returns true for every possible rule, so you will match everything.

If you want to match exactly 1 rule, and you want to know which one it is, you can use this approach in combination with a AgendaEventListener.

What you can do is:

1. implement AgendaEventListener to store which rule has been matched
2. call fireAllRules(1) or write your own agenda filter to limit the amounts of matches to 1
3. evaluate the Listener for which rules has been matched

This does not give you any control over what rule will be matched however. All rules that have NOT been matched when you use a filter, will be matched the next time you fire all rules (unless you limit the rule execution again and so on).

Comment: I have used fireAllRules(1) but it is not working as aspected . it is not returning any matched rule. but fireAllRules() is returning one matched rule

Comment: Could you add a code example yo your question to see what it is you are doing?

Comment: seems like its working i had 2 kind of rules in my drt and 1 was always matching . after passing fireAllRules(2) it worked. Thanks